# Chef cron_d resource action not considering conditions

Tags: chef-infra

I have a recipe defined like below, using chef client 12.21.12

```
cron_d 'cookbooks_report' do
  action ((node.roles.include?('dev') && node.tags.include?('dev-env'))? :create : :delete
  minute '0'
  hour '0'
  weekday '1'
  command .....
end
```

the action with a condition - this is not working as expected.

```
  action ((node.roles.include?('dev') && node.tags.include?('dev-env'))? :create : :delete
```

Does `action` support conditions in cron_d resources?  - looks like this supported, with reference to my comment.

Do i need to use not_if or if_only to apply that condition? - not required for this.

Is there any significant different between
`node.roles.include?('value')` and `node['role'].include?('value')`?

how to check which one works here?

Comment: when the properties action is used with following condition  ` action ( "True" == "True" )? :create : :delete`  it is working... so i think it is the node.roles and node.tags not working in some case.

Comment: `node.roles.inclde?('dev')` has a typo, your answer also seems to likely have typos where `include('value')` needs to be `include?('value')` with a question-mark, etc.  makes it hard to tell what your actual problem is and what are just typographical errors in this SO post.

Comment: The typo was my fault. Eventually there was an issue with the Chef client version.. we had few nodes with 12.0 clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the issue is my local development used chef-client 14 and nodes where running chef-client 12 version.

The `node.roles.include('value')` -> in the recipe threw syntax error with chef-client 14. so it was updated to `node['roles'].include('value')` this got successfully pushed to chef infra server.

but the node chef-client version 12 was not able to resolve it and assumes true always.

below was the chef 12 client with the node['role'].include('value').

```
 * cron_d[demo-cron] action create
    * file[demo-cron legacy named cron.d file] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
    * template[/etc/cron.d/demo-cron] action create
      - create new file /etc/cron.d/demo-cron
      - update content in file /etc/cron.d/demo-cron from none to 15e86f
```

So i updated `node.roles?include('value')` in my recipe and pushed this to chef-server lowering my chef-client version. Then this worked.